# How to use HttpURLConnection to send JSON to server

Tags: android, json

After upgrading the android sdk to 5.1 I see that a whole lot of classes related to HTTP have been deprecated (See the code below).

```
public class HTTPCommandPostJSON implements HTTPCommand {
    private String wurl;
    private JSONObject jsonobj;

    public HTTPCommandPostJSON(String wurl, JSONObject jsonobj) {
        this.wurl = wurl;
        this.jsonobj = jsonobj;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream execute() throws IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(wurl);
        httppostreq.setHeader("json",jsonobj.toString());
//      httppostreq.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",jsonobj);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        httppostreq.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
        return httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
    }
}
```

The above was the code that is working. But since these classes have been deprecated I used the following code -

```
public class HTTPCommandMethodPostJSON implements HTTPCommand{
    private String url;
    private JSONObject object;
    private String json;
    public HTTPCommandMethodPostJSON(String url, JSONObject object){
        this.url=url;
        this.object=object;
        json=object.toString();
    }

    public InputStream execute() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(json.getBytes().length);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(json);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        if(connection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            return connection.getInputStream();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code apparently doesn't work as it returns a blank string in response whereas in the first code I get a JSON object. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the two and what is wrong in the second code?
Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use both of `connection.setDoOutput(true);` (to upload) while using `connection.setDoInput(true);` (to download). Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are missing key name here.

```
json="json="+json; // "json" is the key for you json data
OutputStreamWriter.write(json);//
```